# Add variable to a devise message

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I need to pass a variable to a devise message, devise.registrations.signed_up like :

devise.en.yml:

```
  signed_up: "Welcome to %{my_var}"
```

app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb:

```
   def create
    set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up, :app_name => "my app name"
    super
  end
```

It gives the error: missing interpolation argument because in the super class the set_flash_message sets the message without the variable.

Is there a way to this with devise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to hack into the `def create` of `Devise::RegistrationsController` directly instead of subclassing it and set the flash message there itself.

So, In a way, instead of calling `super` you can simply paste in the code from the devise `create` method and set the flash message to whatever you want there itself.